# Error CS2045 when compiling an application in Visual Studio 2020 for Mac in Release

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working with Visual Studio for Mac version 17.6.8 (build 400).
If I compile an application in debug mode, I do not have any errors or warnings and the application runs correctly, when changing to release mode it gives me the following error:
Error CS2045 /embed switch is only supported when emitting a PDB.
How could I solve this error? Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - that's likely to be trivial C# code, but the *project* file is much more important.

Comment: I have created a standard Maui application, I have compiled it in release mode and it gives the error CS2045

Comment: I install a workload maccatalist 64 and now it's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is what happened when updating to version 17.8.6, I solved it by downgrading to version 17.8.5 of Visual Studio 2022